# Let $R\to S$ be a ring map, then $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}R$ lies under some $\mathfrak{q}$ in $S$ iff $S\otimes_R\kappa(\mathfrak{p})\ne0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Fix a ring map $\varphi:R\to S$, and let $f:\operatorname{Spec}S\to\operatorname{Spec}R$ be the corresponding map of affine schemes. [Remark 10.16.8 of the Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00E6) claims that for some prime $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}R$, we have that $\mathfrak{p} = f(\mathfrak{q}) = \mathfrak{q}^\mathrm{c}$ for some $\mathfrak{q}\in\operatorname{Spec}S$ if and only if $S\otimes_R\kappa(\mathfrak{p})\ne 0$.

However, the proof uses a very elaborate diagram that I can't make sense of, so I'm wondering if there's a simpler proof of this fact.

Comment: Try looking at the proof of Proposition 4.15 in Eisenbud's commutative algebra. This is the lying over theorem. The proposition assumes that $\varphi:R \to S$ is an integral map, but you will see that he actually only needs that $S\otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak{p})\neq 0$.

Comment: Eisenbud additionally assumes that the map is injective.

Comment: Try to reduce to the case where $\varphi$ is injective by seeing what happens when $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq \text{ker} \varphi$. Once you have completed that case, you can mod out by the kernel without loss of generailty.

Comment: Some references to see that $\text{Spec}  (S\otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$ is in fact naturally homeomorphic to ${f^*}^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ are Atiyah Macdonald Problem 3.21 and Matsumura's Commutative Ring theory page 47.